# Appearance of search in Views

Tags: 7, views, search

I use Views module and I've got search to specify results.

[image]

In the search I've got filter for field cena. I set operator between so user can fill in min cena and max cena.

How can I change the appearance of that search? For and foremost I'd like to  remove "And" between inputs for min cena and max cena. If it's possible I also want to create placeholders in inputs for min cena and max cena.

Comment: What do you mean by placeholders?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove the **And** title you need to implement hook_form_alter(). It would look something like this.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_form_FORM_ID_alter().
 */ 
function mymodule_form_views_exposed_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state){
  if ($form['#id'] == 'views-exposed-form-search-page') {
    unset($form['field_price1_value']['max']['#title']);    
  }  
}
```

You will also need to find out the `$form['#id']` so that your code doesn't attempt to change all exposed forms generated by views. Install the Devel module and run.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_form_FORM_ID_alter().
 */ 
function mymodule_form_views_exposed_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state) {
  dsm($form['#id']);
}
```

The devel module will now set a message with each views exposed form and it's `#id`. Copy that and replace `views-exposed-form-search-page` in the first code example. After that you can add a `dsm($form);` to find out what your field name is called in the array (to replace `field_price1_value`).